# Node.js using the Ora spinner package

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to make a fairly simple command line application in Node and I wanted to try adding a spinner. I found the Ora package and I'm having trouble getting it to work. Just about every example I can find uses the setTimeout function to determine when the spinner is spinning, but I would like to have the spinner spin while a lengthy block of code is running. I attempted doing this by using a Promisified function, but I'm not really sure if that's the right thing to be doing. When the I run something with the following form the spinner shows up in the command line but doesn't actually spin. Any help is appreciated.

```js
const ora = require('ora')

const spinner = ora('Doing something...').start()

function doSomething() {
  return new Promise( resolve => {
    // DO SOMETHING TIME-CONSUMING HERE
    resolve('Done')
  })
}

async function main() {
  await doSomething()
  spinner.stop()
}

main()
```

Comment: Works for me. I suspect the issue is in your way of "doing something". *Nothing* in JS should do something for a long time while blocking, because if it does, the entire collaborative multi-tasking logic goes out the window. Can you add the code for the thing you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works OK when using some non-blocking code in the `doSomething` function, e.g.:

```js
function doSomething() {
  return new Promise( resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Done'), 1000);
  })
}
```

But I suspect from your description and the symptoms you describe that you are doing something blocking like:

```js
function doSomething() {
  return new Promise( resolve => {
    let i = 0;
    while (i++ < 1e10) {}
    resolve('Done');
  })
}
```

This will indeed not spin the spinner and that's because JS is single-threaded and uses [cooperative multi-tasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking). So any thread (think "function") that blocks, blocks anything else from happening as well. So a good citizen in JS always returns control and uses a callback or similar to call back when done.

Comment: Yep, I did not understand blocking and what setTimeout does. Thank you! If you don't mind could I ask what the best way to accomplish what I'm looking for? I've looked around and so far I've seen 2 potential routes I could take: a) do the time consuming stuff in chunks and repeatedly relinquish control, or b) use worker threads. Am I on the right track with these?

Comment: "a" is definitely the more common approach. Worker threads are still relatively new, but in theory would lead to better results (at the cost of higher complexity and more rope to potentially hang oneself with).